# Liquibase: How to model collection and relations when creating table?

Tags: java, jpa, liquibase

Consider this entity

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String nickName;
    @ElementCollection
    private final List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany
    private final List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany
    private final List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();

    public User(@Nonnull final String firstName, @Nonnull final String lastName) {
        id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public User() {
        // required by JPA
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Nonnull
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @Nonnull
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Nonnull
    public String getNickName() {
        return nickName;
    }

    public void setNickName(@Nonnull final String nickName) {
        this.nickName = nickName;
    }

    @Nonnull
    public List<String> getEmails() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(emails);
    }

    @Nonnull
    public List<Address> getAddresses() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(addresses);
    }

    @Nonnull
    public List<Phone> getPhones() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(phones);
    }

    public void addAddress(@Nonnull final Address address) {
        addresses.add(address);
    }

    public void addPhone(@Nonnull final Phone phone) {
        phones.add(phone);
    }

    public void addEmail(@Nonnull final String email) {
        emails.add(email);
    }

    // likewise remove address, phones, emails could be added
}
```

I am now creating a liquibase changeset for this table and don't know how to model

```
    @ElementCollection
    private final List<String> emails = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany
    private final List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany
    private final List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();
```

Can someone please help?

My current (incomplete) changeset looks like

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">
    <changeSet author="harit" id="10122014.0907">
        <comment>Add User Table</comment>
        <createTable tableName="user">
            <column name="id" type="VARCHAR(36)">
                <constraints nullable="false" unique="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="firstName" type="VARCHAR(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="lastName" type="VARCHAR(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="nickName" type="VARCHAR(20)"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Answer (score -1):

You would create them with separate changeSets for each of the tables that back emails, addresses, and phones.

I'm not sure what is in those objects, but the changelog would be something like:

```
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
         http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">
    <changeSet author="harit" id="10122014.0907">
        <comment>Add User Table</comment>
        <createTable tableName="user">
            <column name="id" type="VARCHAR(36)">
                <constraints nullable="false" unique="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="firstName" type="VARCHAR(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="lastName" type="VARCHAR(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="nickName" type="VARCHAR(20)"/>
    </changeSet>

    <changeSet author="harit" id="10122014.1001">
        <createTable tableName="address">
            <column name="id" type="VARCHAR(36)">
                <constraints nullable="false" unique="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="line1" type="VARCHAR(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="line2" type="VARCHAR(50)"/>
            <column name="city" type="VARCHAR(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
    </changeSet>

......

</databaseChangeLog>
```